# Data is not saving on Parse.com in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working with online server Parse.com I initialize it at application level using this piece of code

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "7m7gwopMVGDb6ERXufUim9Kk7ITlJ2umzUZUQNTV", "xl31lTPF1Qefv8nwRl4qlGLC6UQOiFfhDKQnJNnN");
    }
```

and then saving test object value using this code but data do not save on the parse object

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

Can anybody tell the reason it's happening. I am trying from two days but didn't found any solution. please help meto do this

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @Zeeshan Shabbir no error in log. just data is not adding in parse.com table

Comment: If you are just starting your application development, then you should seriously consider using another service than Parse.com(I am not saying that its bad). They are stopping their service on 28 Jan,2017(Got this via email from them). If this is an already published app then think about migrating from parse.com

Answer (score 1):

try and check what you get error ..

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("Check ... ", " Success ....");
            } else {
                Log.e("Check ... ", " Ohhh Error  ...." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```